# Git repository folder does not appear in File Explorer

Tags: windows, git, repository, onedrive, github-desktop

Using GitHub Dekstop, I cloned one of my own repositories to my computer, and I named the folder `repo`:

```
C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\DevFiles\repo
```

Now if I navigate to the parent folder `DevFiles`, the repository folder `repo` is not visible.

But if I just paste `C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\DevFiles\repo` into the URL bar, the folder opens like normal.

Why might this be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a problem caused by OneDrive.

On my Windows PC, OneDrive, which creates a backup of every file on the system, was active. I was trying to access the repo from

```
C:\Users\Lenovo\OneDrive\Desktop\DevFiles\repo
```

which is where File Explorer will go by default if I search for `DevFiles`.

GitHub Desktop had stored the repo in

```
C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\DevFiles\repo
```

Not in the `\OneDrive\` folder.